# How to upload file using codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

How to get the InputStream of the uploaded file from codenameone app to my rest full webservices so,that i can able to store blob type of the file in my database table?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the output stream for uploading a file to a webservice?

I would suggest using `MutlipartRequest` which allows you to upload a file to a server. The JavaDoc for that has usage samples.